# When using a delegate, is there a way to get hold of the object response?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

As an example:

> [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync Method (Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144203.aspx)

Normal code:

```
private void wcDownloadStringCompleted( 
    object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
    // The result is in e.Result
    string fileContent = (string)e.Result;
}

public void GetFile(string fileUrl)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
             new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wcDownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fileUrl));
    }
}
```

But if we use an anonymous `delegate` like:

```
public void GetFile(string fileUrl)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
            delegate {
                // How do I get the hold of e.Result here?
            };
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fileUrl));
    }
}
```

How do I get the hold of `e.Result` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
            (s, e) => {
                var result = e.Result;
            };
```

or if you like the delegate syntax

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
            delegate(object s, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
                var result = e.Result;
            };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use an anonymous delegate instead of lambda:

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the following:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            string fileContent = (string)e.Result;
        };
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fileUrl));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers use a lambda expression but, for completeness, note that you can also [specify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) the delegate's arguments:

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
    delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
        // Use e.Result here.
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void GetFile(string fileUrl)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
            (s, e) => {
                // Now you have access to `e.Result` here.
            };
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fileUrl));
    }
}
```